# Woocommerce: Product Category Widget

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, css-selectors, wordpress-theming

I'm using Wordpress for developing my website, Woocommerce plugin and Savoy theme.

I have been dealing with this problem for some time now, so help would be really nice and appreciated.

I am using, basic Product Category Widget, for displaying category hierarchy, for easier movment, between categories. Anyway, on each category on :before I added white circles; with the code bellow.

```
 ul.children .cat-item > a::before{
 content: '';
 display: inline-block;
 width: 17px;
 height: 17px;
 -moz-border-radius: 7.5px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 7.5px;
 border-radius: 7.5px;
 background-color: white;
 margin-right: 9px;
 margin-bottom:-1px;
 cursor: pointer;
 }
```

The problem is that, the text is under the circles, like this --> [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1id7M.png);

What I would like to have is to have circles and text aligned, in one column, without having text under the circles,like this --> [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s6Zbu.png)

If anyone have a solution for my problem, I would really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this is what you want.

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  width: 80px;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

ul li::before{
   content: '';
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   top: 50%;
   transform: translateY(-50%);
   width: 17px;
   height: 17px;
   -moz-border-radius: 7.5px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 7.5px;
   border-radius: 7.5px;
   background-color: red;
   margin-right: 9px;
   margin-bottom:-1px;
   cursor: pointer;
 }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Test</li>
  <li>Very long text</li>
 </ul>
```